# .NET 8 MAUI Blazor Hybrid on Android WearOS: Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, .net, blazor, maui

I'm getting this error when debugging on Android 11 WearOS from VS 2022 17.8.1.
Everything works ok on my phone Android 13.

I'm using .NET 8 MAUI with Blazor Hybrid

It builds ok, but when starting the app this error gets thrown:

```
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException' was thrown.
[mono-rt]    at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniObjectReference type, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 20830
[mono-rt]    at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.FinishCreateInstance(String constructorSignature, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.cs:line 174
[mono-rt]    at Android.Webkit.WebView..ctor(Context context) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Android.Webkit.WebView.cs:line 785
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui.BlazorAndroidWebView..ctor(Context context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\BlazorWebView\src\Maui\Android\BlazorAndroidWebView.cs:line 16
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui.BlazorWebViewHandler.CreatePlatformView() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\BlazorWebView\src\Maui\Android\BlazorWebViewHandler.Android.cs:line 32
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui.IBlazorWebView, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Android.Webkit.WebView, Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].OnCreatePlatformView() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 72
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.OnCreatePlatformElement() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandler.cs:line 184
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.CreatePlatformElement() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 101
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 50
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui.IBlazorWebView, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Android.Webkit.WebView, Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 53
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui.IBlazorWebView, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Android.Webkit.WebView, Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 921
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 863
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement\VisualElement.cs:line 2031
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler handler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 42
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler handler, IContentView page) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 47
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 172
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 47
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 82
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 79
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 53
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 26
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 921
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 863
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement\VisualElement.cs:line 2031
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ScopedFragment.OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\Navigation\ScopedFragment.cs:line 32
[mono-rt]    at AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_inflater, IntPtr native_container, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) in C:\a\_work\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release
et6.0-android\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:line 2031
[mono-rt]    at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L(_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0, IntPtr p1, IntPtr p2) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 367
[mono-rt]   --- End of managed Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException stack trace ---
[mono-rt] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:242)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2576)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2570)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2638)
[mono-rt]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5340)
[mono-rt]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5499)
[mono-rt]   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:698)
[mono-rt]   at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:56)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:413)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:355)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:337)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:324)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:314)
[mono-rt]   at crc64d693e2d9159537db.BlazorAndroidWebView.<init>(BlazorAndroidWebView.java:57)
[mono-rt]   at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.ScopedFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
[mono-rt]   at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.ScopedFragment.onCreateView(ScopedFragment.java:49)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3042)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2952)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:350)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8023)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7651)
[mono-rt]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
[mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   --- End of managed Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException stack trace ---
[mono-rt] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:242)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2576)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2570)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2638)
[mono-rt]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5340)
[mono-rt]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5499)
[mono-rt]   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:698)
[mono-rt]   at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:56)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:413)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:355)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:337)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:324)
[mono-rt]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:314)
[mono-rt]   at crc64d693e2d9159537db.BlazorAndroidWebView.<init>(BlazorAndroidWebView.java:57)
[mono-rt]   at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.ScopedFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
[mono-rt]   at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.ScopedFragment.onCreateView(ScopedFragment.java:49)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3042)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2952)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:350)
[mono-rt]   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8023)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7651)
[mono-rt]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
[mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
[mono-rt]
```

This is my android manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="novit.net.attroll" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="mvp">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="Attendance Roll App" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

And this my package references from Maui .csproj:

```
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Fingerprint" Version="2.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.NFC" Version="0.1.26" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\AttendanceRollApp.LocalDBContext\LocalDBContext.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\AttendanceRollApp.SharedUI\AttendanceRollApp.SharedUI.csproj">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I've tried adding different packages from nuget, from Xamarin.androidx.. with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you've figured out by now that Maui doesn't support WearOS, but that said I've gotten quite a bit of Maui working on my wearable devices.

Its just that every once in a while, something just doesn't work and i need to work around the issue.  So you need to go step by step working on and for your target device.
There's just no way to develop on a mobile device targeting sdk v33 and expect to get anywhere...